# FFmpeg command to rotate an MP4 file by 90º

Tags: ffmpeg, rotate

Can I rotate (save, reencode) a .mp4 file with ffmpeg?

The only thing I found was on the mailinglist saying `-vfilters "rotate=90"` but ffmpeg says that "there are no vfilters". I tried `-vf`, it says there is "no rotate".

If I try to do it in VLC, it simply does not rotate and kills the audio. I'm on a Mac.

```
FFmpeg version git-svn-r23607, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun 14 2010 23:52:55 with gcc 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5659)
  configuration: 
  libavutil     50.19. 0 / 50.19. 0
  libavcodec    52.76. 0 / 52.76. 0
  libavformat   52.68. 0 / 52.68. 0
  libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
  libavfilter    1.20. 0 /  1.20. 0
  libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
```

Comment: In case you really only want to change the metadata without re-encoding, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31683689/111036) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15336581/111036) : `-metadata:s:v rotate="90" -codec copy` or maybe `... rotate=0 ...` to reset the rotation metadata.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe it should be configured with `--enable-vfilters` before compilation?
BTW, mencoder does the job well, but you'll have to reencode the video:

`mencoder -oac copy -ovc lavc -vf rotate=1 original.mp4 -o 90_CW_rotated.mp4`
`mencoder -oac copy -ovc lavc -vf rotate=2 original.mp4 -o 90_CCW_rotated.mp4`

Comment: I had vfilters enabled. they just purged the algorithm from the packege, who knows why -_-

I fixed it already, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

With the current version pulled from SVN, you can rotate video using -vf "transpose=1".
Here's an example:

```
ffmpeg -vf "transpose=1" -i input.mp4 output.mp4
```

[docs + options for transpose command are here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#transpose-1)

(here's how I built ffmpeg in case this helps)

```
svn checkout svn://svn.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg/trunk ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg
./configure --enable-shared  --disable-mmx --arch=x86_64
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're disabling MMX? I don't see a point in that.

Comment: I had to put the filter after the input for it to work: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "transpose=1" output.mp4`