# How can I rotate MOV and mp4 files in Windows Live Photo Gallery?

Tags: windows-7, video, mp4, rotate, windows-photo-gallery

I am using Windows Live Photo Gallery on Windows 7 to manage my photos and video clips from camera/phone. If I import photos/videos from camera, it is smart enough to rotate as necessary, but I have some old stuff from iPhoto which is not rotated and I'd like to, specifically video clips.

AVI files have been easy to rotoate. Select the video, rotate. I am unable to rotate clips which are MOV or mp4. Is it a codec issue?

I bought Quicktime Pro to follow the simple suggestion provided here: [How do I rotate video (MOV) file on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/174035/how-do-i-rotate-video-mov-file-on-windows) but while it rotates it when playing in QT, it does not do so in WLPG.

I don't want to get Picasa just for this purpose. Any other ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [FFmpeg command to rotate an MP4 file by 90º](http://superuser.com/questions/162259/ffmpeg-command-to-rotate-an-mp4-file-by-90%c2%ba)

Answer (score 0):

I have tested both the solutions in [question 162259](https://superuser.com/questions/162259/ffmpeg-rotate-mp4-90) and they seem to work fine, on my windows boxes I usually use [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/). It isn't the answer to how to in WLPG, but this is a fantastic video tool for the toolbox especially if you want to crank out several files from a command line easily.

Comment: Does the output file have the same metadata (date/time)?

Comment: There wasn't much there to begin with, but the only thing I saw different was the height and width.

Comment: I was referring mostly to the date/time of the clips. I had gone through a bunch of video clips and adjusted the date/time some months ago, would be painful to re-do it :-/

Comment: ??? Sorry, the mp4s I have laying around, or create don't have valid dates that I can find in the medadata so I can't say.